# Changes made to project by opening in Xcode beta

Tags: ios, xcode, certificate, provisioning-profile, xcode8

I have a project which I opened in the Xcode 8 beta, and attempted to submit it to the App Store from there (before realizing that was impossible).  Now I am attempting to submit it from Xcode 7, using a Mac on El Capitan, and receive the message "No matching provisioning profiles found for application".

I have tried a variety of things to fix this.  I have restarted Xcode and the Mac, logged out and in again with my Apple ID, removed and re-downloaded the profiles countless times, created a new set of profiles and used those, cleaned the project, and even reset my certificate.  I still get the error.

Is there something changed or added by the beta software that I need to remove to submit the app?  Or should I completely recreate the project?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what it was, but I fixed the problem by restoring the project to a version from before I opened it in Xcode beta, and then copying my new code over.